# Vector to grid - Computing statistics by grid cells

Tags: qgis, vector, grids-graticules, analysis

I have a vector point data from drifting buoys (speed, direction, sst, slp) that I want to analyse in a grid. What are the right tools for this?

Example of my points data below. Each point has the variables lat, long, date, time, SST, SLP, direction and velocity.
  [image: example_points]

First I need to create a grid of the desired size (im thinking 1/4 degree)and then do basic statistics within each cell to create an overall picture. Basic stats would be a number of points in a cell, mean, max and min of the variables.

I tried to rasterize the vectors but can't figure out what the results are showing. I want to compute the means, max and mins for different variable in a cell. Any suggestions?

[image: example_rasterize]

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your data, please? Moreover, what are your requirement against the grid cells?

Comment: Additionally, you may read these threads [Create grid where points is centroid? QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115938/create-grid-where-points-is-centroid-qgis), [QGIS - Create Grid - Create Fishnet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjzpull6T94) and [Summing data from a column in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/summing-data-from-a-column-in-attribute-table/301852#301852).

Comment: @Taras I added some pictures and a few more details. It should be relatively straight forward. Im quite now to QGIS but have seen this kind of analysis done before.